# Output accuracy on test data during training

Tags: tensorflow

As the title implies, I would like to find out if it is possible to output the accuracy on the **test** data as well as the training data, to see at which point my model starts to overfit and result in worse performance on test data. However, I do not know how to do this and I was not able to find an answer online.

To train the model, I am making use of the built-in `fit` method.

Is this possible?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you using custom training loop? Keras's `fit` method? Or any other predefined loop? Short answer is yes. How? Depends on what code you are using. So if you want a more specific answer, you should show us your training loop.

Comment: Hi. I am using the built-in ```fit``` method.

Comment: If by *test* data you mean validation data, you can do so by simply adding 'accuracy' to your metrics. But if you really mean *test* data, you should write a callback and inside its `on_epoch_end` function you can print the accuracy on your testset. If you need more info, let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it is best to partition your data into a training set, a validation set and a test set. I typically use 80% of the data for the training set, 10% for the validation set and 10% for the test set. `model.fit()` provides the ability to specify both a training set and a validation set as parameters. For each epoch of training, TensorFlow will produce a printout of the training accuracy, training loss, validation accuracy and validation loss if you set verbose to either 1 or 2 and you include 'accuracy' as a metric in `model.compile()`. You can then look at the loss values (the best to plot them using `history.history`) and determine if you are overfitting. There are several ways to develop a validation set. If your data is not produced by generators, you can specify the validation_split parameter in `model.fit()` to create a validation set automatically. Alternatively, you can use ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory to generate a validation set by setting the parameter `validation_split`. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/)

Comment: I am using a dataset which I created myself which is a specific version of the Free Music Archive dataset. Making use of ```validation_split=0.2```  within the ```fit``` function_(using 0.2 as an example)_ has done exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!